# Как узнать, каким по счёту является элемент map в Golang?

Tags: golang, бот

Для игрового бота надо составить топ-10 игроков по количеству денег. Игроки записаны в map[int64]User, где int64 — ID игрока. Также надо написать место запросившего игрока (переменная peer)
Я хотел попробовать перебором, но это было бы долго в случаях с большим количеством игроков и, например, самым бедным запросившим

Comment: а peer - это свойство User?

Comment: Map  в GoLang - это неотсортированная структура. Поэтому, никак "напрямую". Для этого нужно немного поработать - составьте структуру id-monye, отсортируйте, а дальше просто возьмите 10 элемент

https://yourbasic.org/golang/sort-map-keys-values/

если это нужно делать часто и много - придется либо держать две структуры в паралель, либо придумать свою структуру.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, peer — отдельная переменная

Comment: @KoVadim, Спасибо за ответ!) Не могли бы ли вы написать это как ответ?)

Comment: для хорошего ответа надо ещё и код написать...